# How to connect potentiometer to an Arduino board and a motor using a large power source at the same time

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, motor, potentiometer, pid-controller

I want to use a PID system to control a potentiometer with a motor. I'm going to run the system on an Arduino so I need to connect my potentiometer to the Arduino so it can take whatever data it needs from it. I also need to run a large amount of current (350 watts)  through the potentiometer to power a separate motor but I don't want to burn through my Arduino.

How can I hook both the Arduino and the large power source to my potentiometer without them interacting? I do have an engineering background but it's in mechanical so I circuitry from a physics background but not so much practical. I'm kind of a noob at this stuff so try and use simple terminology if you can.

Comment: You can't deliver 350W through any potentiometer small enough to use with a breadboard. Even 350mW might be a stretch.

Comment: "*... a large amount of current (350 watts) ...*" Current is measured in amperes. Power is measured in watts.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question, with a reference to this one, describing what you wish to achieve (rather than how) and including only "end point" hardware - eg You wish to use an Arduino, You need to achieve some task - don't mention motor in detail unless you have one you strongly wish to use. Once people know your actual requirement it makes it much easier to help.

Answer (score 4):

You have the whole concept all wrong. The way this is done is that a low wattage potentiometer is connected between the supply rails of the Arduino MCU with the wiper connected to an analog input to the MCU. This input is then configured to be read via the A/D converter in the MCU and results in readings that indicate the positional rotation of the potentiometer.

You then equip the motor with a driver circuit using MOSFETS capable handling the current requirements of the motor load. This driver would have an input that can switch the driver on and off according to the logic level output of an Arduino digital pin. This output pin can be directly turned on and off via a software PWM algorithm or be setup to be driven with a PWM timer structure in the MCU HW.

The PWM duty cycle driven to the output pin is determined by the value read from the A/D corresponding to the potentiometer position. Of course some mathematical scaling of the A/D value will have to be done before applying the corresponding value to the PWM algorithm.

Comment: Yep, that's about the size of it. Make sure you set the PWM frequency above 20KHz (above most human's audible range) to prevent motor noise at less than 100% duty-cycle. (unless you motor isn't susceptible) The Arduino clock is fast enough to still give you 1% PWM increments at that frequency (a Pico will give you ~ 256 increments in duty-cycle at 24KHz)